# sklearn dcg_score not working as expected

Tags: scikit-learn, ranking, information-retrieval

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import dcg_score
true_relevance = np.asarray([[10]])
scores = np.asarray([[.1]])
dcg_score(true_relevance, scores)
```

The below code should produce 10 as the dcg_score. The formula from wikipedia gives `10/log2 = 10` But, instead I get `ValueError: Only ('multilabel-indicator', 'continuous-multioutput', 'multiclass-multioutput') formats are supported. Got binary instead`

Did anyone encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

Since computing dcg on a single element is not meaningful, the sklearn library requires at least two y_true and y_score elements in the corresponding arrays.
You can check this by exploring the sklearn code (or through debugging): https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b611bf873bd5836748647221480071a87/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L158

Like:

```
true_relevance = np.asarray([[10, 5]])
scores = np.asarray([[.1, .2]])
dcg_score(true_relevance, scores)
```